# On which layer of Clean Architecture hierarchy must be the entities with application-specific properties?

Tags: use-case, clean-architecture

From the [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/441244/375105) to [Must the use cases extend the entities in Clean Architecture?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/441243/375105) I have known that the **use cases** must NOT extend the **entities**. It's fine, but what do I have to do with the properties of entities which are depending on the application?

> Very strictly speaking, these rules (*note: the enterprise business rules*) would make or save the
> business money, irrespective of whether they were implemented on a
> computer. They would make or save money even if they were executed
> manually.

The below entity is matching with this concept because each product has a title which could be written on the physical label and price:

```typescript
class Product {

  public title: string;
  public price__dollars__withoutTax: number;

  public constructor(properties: Readonly<{ title: string; price__dollars__withoutTax: number; }>) {
    this.title = properties.title;
    this.price__dollars__withoutTax = properties.price__dollars__withoutTax;
  }

}
```

Unlike this, the below class has some fields which exist only inside the application - `ID`, `createdAt__ISO86101`, `updatedAt__ISO86101`

```typescript
class Product {

  public readonly ID: number = Product.generateID();

  public title: string;
  public price__dollars__withoutTax: number;

  public createdAt__ISO86101: string;
  public updatedAt__ISO86101?: string;

  public constructor(properties: Readonly<{ title: string; price__dollars__withoutTax: number; }>) {
    this.title = properties.title;
    this.price__dollars__withoutTax = properties.price__dollars__withoutTax;
    this.createdAt__ISO86101 = new Date().toISOString();
  }


  private static counterForID_Generating = -1;
  private static generateID(): number {
    Product.counterForID_Generating++;
    return Product.counterForID_Generating;
  }  
}
```

How the second version of `Product` class should be organized in the Clean Architecture hierarchy?

[image]

Comment: There is nothing inherently “implemented by a computer” about an Id or a time stamp.

Comment: Why `createdAt__ISO86101` and `updatedAt__ISO86101`  are application specific? If `Product`  as an entity of the domain is so `abstract`, then let it be so. Don't make it concrete. It can be just an "abstraction" too. By the way, there're other techniques to expand data models. One of them can be persisting additional data in different places. Another is via decorators and composition. Remember that the domain will not care how data is persisted or managed "out" of its scope.

Comment: @candied_orange, Why? ID is not the product code, just some token which being used for the searching, for example, or by frontend framework in iterative rendering. The timestamp is not the production data of the physical product, it just the registration date/time in the database.

Comment: @Laiv, because `createdAt__ISO86101` is not the date/time of the production of physical product - it just the date of adding to digital database. The `updatedAt__ISO86101` is the date/time of updating the data in digital database. "By the way, there're other techniques to expand data models." - thank you for the advise. Sounds great, but have you some links with examples?

Comment: The criteria you gave was: “They would make or save money even if they were executed manually.” you can set and keep time stamps and IDs manually. Ask an old librarian what index cards were originally used for.